# Method from WCF Service returns different types of Objects?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible for a WCF Service method to return different types?

I already tried with Object but since it's not a DataContract type it doesn't work properly.

How can I do it?

Comment: You want to think about how a caller will use the service. How will the caller determine which type has been returned. Consider whether the caller will ever be a platform other than .NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`known types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx). Those could also be defined in the config file using the `<system.runtime.serialization>` section (see *Additional Ways to Add Known Types* in the article).

This being said you probably want to define a base data contract type that all other possible data contracts will derive from and have your operation return this base data contract instead of using object.